# VS2022 - 17.8 Preview 5 can't hot reload on multiple containers

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose

For the one who are wainting for hot reload on .NET 8 and docker like me, do you have the same behaviour with VS 2022 17.8 preview 3 ?

Edit 20/10/2023 : Same behaviour on Preview 4
Edit 25/10/2023 : Same behaviour on Preview 5

Here is what i'm testing :

Repro Steps

```
Open VS - create a project - set API Web Asp.net core
    Activate Https
    Activate Docker
    Docker OS - Linux
    Use Controllers
    
Add another project Test2 with the same specifications 

On project 1 - Add docker orchestrator
On project 2 - Add docker orchestrator

Put a breakpoint on "return Enumerable.Range(1, 5)" into GetWeatherForecast Action into WeatherForecastController in both projects Test1 and Test2

Start docker-compose

    https://localhost:{YourPortToTest1}/swagger/index.html is showing
    Test Get /WeatherForecast Action --> breakpoint is raised
        change "return Enumerable.Range(1, 5)" to "return Enumerable.Range(1, 50)"
        hot reolading do the job
        
    go to https://localhost:{YourOtherPortToTest2}/swagger/index.html
    Test Get /WeatherForecast Action --> breakpoint is raised
        change "return Enumerable.Range(1, 5)" to "return Enumerable.Range(1, 50)"
        visual studio is freezing
```

Comment: Note : Still the same behaviour with 17.8 preview 4

Comment: Note : Still the same behaviour with 17.8 preview 5

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen any blog post claiming that Hot Reload works across containers. The application running inside a container is essentially a remote machine. There's an open Github Issue [Will DockerTools ever support ".NET Hot Reload"](https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/322) where people report their *experiments* with Hot Reload but ... it's still open. It's definitely not an announced feature

Comment: Besides, the question doesn't contain enough information to check if it could work based on the GH issue experiments. All experiments use Ctrl+F5 to start *without* an attached debugger. It seems they use multi-stage Dockerfiles as well.

Comment: One of the comments says that F5 is planned for 17.8, not that it's already available. In another comment Hot Reload failed with a change that occasionally failed outside Docker as well.

Comment: Hello, according to what's i have read on microsoft community and my experiments, hot reload does works. It works on 17.7 with no debugger attached (i-e ctrl + F5) and it have been anounced for 17.8 with debugger attached. In my test above one of the two projects can hot reload even with debugger attached, the other project freeze when trying to apply modifications. See "Cross platform Enc/Hot Reload debugging support" in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview